# What in Windows 10 plays system sounds?

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds

My Windows 10 system has been playing at least one kind of system sound lately, without me being able to determine what the hell is being communicated, if that's even relevant -- I don't know which process plays the sound, there are no visual alerts, like, for instance, notifications.

This drives me nuts.

I am not the type to install third party drivers or services, it's as vanilla as I can keep it. I can provide the list of services running, but there isn't anything strange, really.

Is there anything I can do to debug this to understand what and why plays the so far two sound clips I keep hearing?

I've tried Process Explorer to find a handle with search pattern "WAV", and it pointed me to two dozens of `svchost.exe` processes, which isn't really immediately helpful. I've tried to locate the sound in System Sounds, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Nothing in your notification screen? Can you record the sound and post the wav or mp3 on a file sharing site?

Comment: Thanks. I'll do my best to record it, but it plays something like once every two hours of system use, and of course at a completely random time. I guess I'll dedicate 64 kbit per second worth of audio stream for a day worth of audio in the end.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Fair find -- didn't show up when I was writing up the question. If the duplicate Q&A will help me, I'll delete or have this question closed.